# My Arrray Value is Overwritten in nested foreach loop

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($model_name as $md) {
    foreach ($years as $y) {
        $model_w_year[$y] = $md;
    } 
}
```

It's obviously not working. The array it outputs looks like like:

```
Array
(
    [1994] => Maxima
    [1995-1998] => Maxima
)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1994] => Sentra
    [1995-1998] => Maxima
)
```

Model_name is a $_SESSION['model_name'] from previous page and years is a form array

```
echo "<form action='engine.php' method='post'>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($model_name); $i++) {
   echo "Enter year or year range for: ", $model_name[$i], 
       " <input type='text' name='years[]'></input><br />";
}
```

And here are all array structures that I have:

```
Model make: 
Nissan
model name: 
Array
(
    [0] => Sentra
    [1] => Maxima
)

Number of models:  
2
Number of years: 
Array
(
    [0] => 1994
    [1] => 1995-1998
)

Model with Year: 
Array
(
    [1994] => Maxima
    [1995-1998] => Maxima
)
```

Answer: yes I want the year to be the key and the model to be the value.

Comment: do you want each value of `$year` to be assigned to one value of `$model_name` ?

Comment: add more information on your array structure and values `$year` and `$model_name`

Comment: @hexblot Yes it would be array ( "1998" => "Maxima", "1994 => "Sentra" ); or whatever the user inputs.

Comment: @Baba I've addded the array structure for `$year` and `$model_name`

Comment: @MikeHoy just use `array_combine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping structure doesn't seem to make sense if you are trying to somehow get certain key value grouping out of the `$model_name` and `$years` arrays. Because for each model name, you will loops through every available year and set the value to the current model name.  So whatever model name is last in your array, will end end up being set for all model years.

Based on your question it looks like the model name array and the matching value in the years array would have the same numerical index. So, you might use something like `array_combine()` to merge these values

```
$merged_array = array_combine($years, $model_name);
```

This would use `$years` as the array keys and `$model_name` as the values.

Comment: I've added more info, hopefully that helps.

Comment: That solves it. Thanks, array_combine didn't work the first time I used it because I tried it within the for loop, bad mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Brant's answear explains why your code doesn't work the way you want it to. If I understand you right, you have two arrays, `$model_name` and `$years`, where `$years[$i]` is the years entered by the user for the i:th model. That is, the arrays look like this

```
Array (
  [???] => Sentra
  [???] => Maxima
)
```

and this

```
Array (
  [0] => 1994
  [1] => 1995-1998
)
```

In that case, I think this code should do the trick:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($model_name as $md) {
  $model_w_year[$years[$i]] = $md;
  $i++;
}
```

It's not very beautiful, but I think it should work.

Comment: Just read Mike's edit and the new info. Mike's way is much nicer than mine, so use his.